# Команды node.js не работают

Tags: node.js

Ребята, не работают утилиты node.js, какую бы команду я не писал, консоль выдает ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, где ошибка и что не так делаю.

Comment: node.js не работает? А разработчики-то не знают.

Comment: Извините, а вы читали сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: а зачем вы пытаетесь запустить node.js внутри node.js?

Comment: We need to go deeper

Comment: @VladD зачем так жестоко, вдруг человек просто не знает английского.

Answer (score 5):

В сообщениях об ошибках написано, что npm надо запускать в обычной командной строке. А то, в чем вы пытаетесь вбивать команды - это консоль node js.

Попробуйте вбить те же команды в обычном cmd.